# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not find details for contract ID

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

While trying to invoke and query with the existing installed chaincode in the network,
using caliper launch master --caliper-workspace . --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/scenario/simple/createPool.yaml --caliper-networkconfig networks/Azure_fabric-go.yaml --caliper-flow-only-test

The following errors are I am facing,

(node:44363) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not find details for contract ID W1CC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening when the caliper can't found the name of your contract. Make sure name of your `chaincode` is correct or it already installed in channel.

Example: - `/benchmarks/scenario/simple/open.js`

```
module.exports.run = function() {
  let args = generateWorkload();
  return bc.invokeSmartContract(contx, 'nameofchaincode', 'v0', args, 100); 
};
```